# Reduce duplication in Nginx site-conf files

Tags: nginx

The following code repeats itself in all my Nginx site-conf files (`sites-available/domain.tld.conf`). I could have 50 websites and all 50 site-conf files will have the same duplication:

```
location / {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}

location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|ttf|woff|pdf)$ {
    expires 365d;
}
```

Is there a way to reduce duplication (without unsing `include`)?

Maybe, to put these in the global `nginx.conf` file?

### Update for Richard Smith:

Putting this server block in the end of `nginx.conf` makes the server restart to fail:

```
server {
    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|ttf|woff|pdf)$ {
        expires 365d;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `location` directive needs to be inside a `server` block. To avoid duplication across multiple domain names, use an `include` directive or use a regular expression `server_name`.

Comment: Richard, please see update in my answer.

Comment: @fayalikt `sudo nginx -t` should test all configuration files and return errors and warnings locations.

Comment: Regular expression server names are [documented here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names). You may be able to replace your existing server blocks with a single block. You cannot inherit location blocks into multiple servers (unless you can use include).

Comment: What is the changing part as such for different domains?

Answer (score 1):

Put all your repeating configuration in a separate file and include it.
I prefer to have it in a known location, and to split it based on the topic of the file, for example:

```
include /etc/nginx/cache_static_files.conf ;
include /etc/nginx/proxy_to_php73_fpm.conf ;
```

NB: use **full/absolute** paths for the included configuration files.